# How can I create a layout where there is a 2x2 button section to the right of an image in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

[image: This is what I want to create.]

I have tried so many combinations of using containers that I don't know what else to do. Also, all the buttons must have equal dimensions, and the section of buttons must stretch to the end of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

- Start with a `parentContainer` with a  row flexDirection so that items are laid left to right instead of up and down.
- Add two views to `parentContainer`: `imageContainer` and `buttonContainer`. Divvy width among the two according to your layout desires (image from question suggest 50%/50%)
- add centering styles to `imageContainer`  and use `onLayout` to determine width and height of image.
- add row flexDirection and flexWrap to `buttonContainer`.
- Create a buttonStyle make sure it has width of 50%

Here's a [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/KQvEvAVMA) that brings it all together:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Image, Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const Button = ({ title, titleStyle, ...touchableProps }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      {...touchableProps}
      style={[styles.button, touchableProps.style]}>
      <Text style={[{ textAlign: 'center' }, titleStyle]}>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  // used to set image size
  const [{ width, height }, setViewDimensions] = React.useState({});
  // update image size on imageview layout chagnes
  const onLayout = ({ nativeEvent: { layout } }) => setViewDimensions(layout);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.parentContainer}>
        <View style={styles.imageContainer} onLayout={onLayout}>
          <Image
            source={require('./assets/snack-icon.png')}
            style={{ width, height: width }}
            resizeMode="contain"
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Button title="1" />
          <Button title="2" />
          <Button title="3" />
          <Button title="4" />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  parentContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  imageContainer: {
    width: '50%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    width: '50%',
    backgroundColor: 'lightgreen',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  button: {
    width: '50%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderRightWidth: 1,
  },
});
```